# when can I use methods and when command line options?

Tags: powershell

Why can I use `split` as a method and command line switch, but not `join`? How do I discover what flags (e.g. `-join`) an object supports?

```
> "a,b,c,d" -split ','
a
b
c
d
> "a,b,c,d".split(',')
a
b
c
d
> "a,b,c,d".split(',').join(';')
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'join'.
At line:1 char:1
+ "a,b,c,d".split(',').join(';')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

> "a,b,c,d".split(',') -join ';'
a;b;c;d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why can I use split as a method and command line switch, but not join?*

Because [`String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects have a method `Split()`, but [arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) don't have a method `Join()`, whereas `-split` and `-join` are [operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) provided by PowerShell.

The `String` class does have a (static) `Join()` method complementing `Split()`, though. You use it like this:

```
[String]::Join(',', ("a,b,c,d" -split ','))
```

Another thing you could do is set the [output field separator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/psmdtagfaq-what-is-ofs/) (`$OFS`) to your delimiter character and embed your array in a string:

```
$OFS = ','
"$("a,b,c,d" -split ',')"
```

BTW, [`-split`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx) and [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) don't work the same way, so don't confuse them. The former uses a regular expression, the latter a character array.

```
PS C:\> 'a  b' -split '\s+'
a
b
PS C:\> 'a  b'.Split('\s+')
a  b
PS C:\> 'a,b;c' -split (',', ';')
Cannot convert value ";" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in
a correct format."
At line:1 char:9
+ 'a,b;c' -split (',', ';')
+         ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

PS C:\> 'a,b;c'.Split((',', ';'))
a
b
c
```

> *How do I discover what flags (e.g. -join) an object supports?*

By reading the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx). `-join` isn't a method, flag, or commandline switch. It's a PowerShell [operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you will do:

```
"String" | Get-Member
```

you will see that there is no `Join` Method available, only Split().

You can Use however the `-Join` Operator instead, which exist for `-Split` as well

In your Example:

```
"a,b,c,d".split(',') -join ";"
```

or Use the: `[string]::Join()` Class

Comment: how do i see all operators ?

Comment: `Get-Help about_Operators`